# Where to store Citavi Project File for Team Projects

Tags: windows, collaboration, google-drive

We are working with a group of 10 people on a citavi group project. Currently the project file is stored in google drive. A least once a day the file is getting asynchron for some people, ultimatly resulting in data inconsistency. What would be the best way to store a file so everyone can write at the same time. We are on the campus network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described [here](http://service.citavi.com/KB/a116/14061-why-should-projects-not-be-saved-a-dropbox.aspx) dropbox and drive are not suited for storing citavi projects.
I found out that you would a server that supports SMB/CIFS-Protocol. [Source (german)](http://support.citavi.de/forum/viewtopic.php?f=88&t=4902)